# about android emulator diskimage

Tags: android, diskimage

> The emulator provides a default user-data disk image. At startup, the emulator creates ***the default image*** as a copy of ***the system user-data image*** (user-data.img), described above. The emulator stores the new image with the files of the active AVD.

from:http://androidappdocs.appspot.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html

1)What does the default images mean?(userdata.img?)
2)What does the system user-data image mean?(userdata-qemu.img?)

Answer (score 1):

The default images, `system.img` and `userdata.img` are copied from the relevant platform folder in your SDK installation.

e.g. these two image files would be copied from `$ANDROID_HOME/platforms/android-8/images` if you created an Android 2.2 emulator.

The `system.img` is the `/system` partition — the OS and pre-installed applications, while the `user-data.img` includes some non-system applications.